# IndexError: list index out of range. Не запускается обучение нейросети

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=15, verbose=1)

Comment: какие у вас размерности тензоров `x_train` и `y_train`?

Answer (score 0):

---

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=15, verbose=1)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _is_list_of_scalars(inp)
621       return True
622     if isinstance(inp, (list, tuple)):
--> 623       return ListsOfScalarsDataAdapter._is_list_of_scalars(inp[0])
624     return False
625

IndexError: list index out of range